# Method of filling several cells in a grid quickly in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, fill

I am using Photoshop 7.0 and want to fill a grid with diffent colors

After creating a grid with the pattern-tool (works fine), each cell has to be individually clicked and filled with the filling-tool.

Is there a way to quickly fill several cells with color? instead of clicking each cell? - similar to the "brush" tool? - example below

[image]

[image: here a screenshot of my work:]
[image: here a screenshot of the layer panel]

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're working on and the layer panel? I'm a bit unclear as to why you need to select these individual cells and how brush tool comes into play. Which means I'm quite sure there's a better way but not sure which is best for you without knowing more.

Comment: hello @Ryan, 
if there is another, better way to do this, I am open to improvement. 
I added the screenshots above. 
thanks.